# Как получить путь к папке приложения на android-устройстве. Unity3D

Tags: javascript, android, c#, xml, unity3d

Есть код который открывает xml-файл:

```
string fileXmlPath = Application.dataPath;
    fileXmlPath += "/Data/Spells.xml";
    if (File.Exists(fileXmlPath)) //Если данный файл существует 
    {
        xmlSpells = new XmlDocument(); //Создаем переменную для нашего файла 
        xmlSpells.Load(fileXmlPath); //Открываем файл по пути, который мы разобрали выше 
    }
```

Вот только проверка if(false), в логи не вывело вход (проверил). И еще: по этому пути файл открывается когда тестишь в самом Unity, а когда запускаешь apk на устройстве - его нет.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Application.dataPath` - **iOS player**: <path to player app bundle>/<AppName.app>/Data ..........возможно на ios дополнительное указание `Data` не нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я пока что под iOS даже не смотрю, мне бы и с андроидом разобратся

Comment: спутал немного..ночь...улица. фонарь. аптека

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод **Application.persistentDataPath** вместо **Application.dataPath**. 
Выберите необходимую вам настройку в *Build Setting -> Player Setting -> Other Settings -> Write Access*. Если укажете *Internal Only*, то тогда метод будет указывать на */data/data/com.your.appid/files*. Если укажете *External (SD card)*, то метод будет указывать на *Android/file/com.your.appid/files* на SD карте.

(!) Обычный пользователь не сможет найти данные файлы без рут прав

Answer (score -1):

Android не видит файл, потому что unity все в бинарники кладет, и папка Data становится не доступной.
Можно сделать так, папку Data надо положить в папку Resources

```
string fileXmlPath = Application.dataPath;
    fileXmlPath += "/Data/Spells.xml";
    TextAsset ta=Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileXmlPath);
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(ta.text);
```

А зачем тебе собственно грузить xml? Ты его потом парсишь, чтобы извлечь данные? Это можно через сериализацию класса сделать System.Xml.Serialization

```
public class TestXML{

[XmlElement("a1")]
public Vector3 Var1;

[XmlArray("a2")]
[XmlArrayItem("b1")]
public List<Vector3> Var2;}
```

Тут если просто переменная XmlElement, если массив то XmlArray + XmlArrayItem

Comment: Пишите ваши ответы более развернутыми. Приложите код, который демострирует решение проблемы.