# Загрузка данных с сервера в мобильном приложении на Unity

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

При запуске приложения в Unity, загрузка и сохранение данных в JSON файл работает нормально, но когда проверяю на телефоне, новые данные (загруженные с сервера) не обновляются. Загрузка с сервера прошла, мы их записали в тот же файл, но данные не обновились. В чём проблема?

Загрузка данных происходит через `Resourses`:

```
string dataAsJson =  Resources.Load<TextAsset>(dataFileName).text;
```

Сохранение данных с сервера:

```
string dataAsJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(_newData, true);

File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Data.json", dataAsJson);
```

Думаю, что возможная проблема в том, что после того, как собрана `apk`, `Resourses` становятся `read only`, но не уверен.

В Unity код работает, а на телефоне нет. Как исправить или как это сделать?

Comment: `но когда проверяю на телефоне,` - каком? Ios? Android? windowsphone?  А то там пути различаются. Посмотри также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667432/191482

Comment: При билде все в бинарники уходит, только read, смотрите в сторону AssetBundle